# How to use the 'as' keyword to alias a table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, table-alias

I'm trying to execute this query in Oracle SQL Developer:

```
SELECT G.Guest_ID, G.First_Name, G.Last_Name
FROM Guest AS G
  JOIN Stay AS S ON G.Guest_ID = S.Guest_ID
WHERE G.City = 'Miami' AND S.Room = '222';
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 - "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 12
```

I don't see any problem in line 2 and the error is not very descriptive. It appears to be something to do with the `as` keyword. If I remove it, it works fine. However, I want my queries to be very verbose. Therefore, I must figure out a way to fix whatever the problem is without removing the `as` keyword.

This is the structure of the tables involved:

```
CREATE TABLE GUEST
(
  GUEST_ID       NUMBER               NOT NULL,
  LAST_NAME      VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  FIRST_NAME     VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  CITY           VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  LOYALTY_NUMBER VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)    
);

CREATE TABLE STAY
(
  STAY_ID        NUMBER                         NOT NULL,
  GUEST_ID       NUMBER                         NOT NULL,
  HOTEL_ID       NUMBER                         NOT NULL,
  START_DATE     DATE,
  NUMBER_DAYS    NUMBER, 
  ROOM           VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
);
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Probably you are coming from an experience of SQL server. Unlike SQL server, in Oracle SQL, to alias a table you just need to use alias names just like @dystroy has answered.

Comment: @justCallMeBiru In most systems you *can* use `AS` but it's optional.

Comment: Use of `AS` keyword for table alias is not ANSI SQL standard.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use `AS` for table aliasing on many SQL servers (at least MsSQL, MySQL, PostrgreSQL) but it's always optional and on Oracle it's illegal.

So remove the `AS` :

```
SELECT G.Guest_ID, G.First_Name, G.Last_Name
FROM Guest G
```

Comment: I want the query to have the `as` keyword like I do in my MSSQL queries.

Comment: @Marcos Oracle isn't MSSQL

Comment: Oracle has the `as` keyword. Why can't I use it?

Comment: You can use it for field aliasing.

Comment: I don't find Oracle's documentation for table aliasing but [this one should do](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/4761.tables-and-column-aliases.aspx).

Comment: I guess this is correct. This is what I get for learning the Microsoft way first.

Comment: Oracle's documentation for the `SELECT` [*table_reference*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55230) does **not** show `AS` before *t_alias*; compare with [*select_list*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55229), which clearly shows the (optional) `AS` before *c_alias*. So the documentation does say it is allowed for column alias, and does not say it's allowed for table aliasing; therefore it isn't.

Comment: @Marcos If your problem is to have the same queries both on MsSQL and Oracle, remove the AS completely from table aliasing. It's optional on MsSQL.

Comment: I saw a [video](https://youtu.be/aI0NpZsrui4?t=2m56s) and it shows that Oracle SQL Developer has the `AS` keyword

Comment: @DylanChen yes, for column aliasing, not for table aliasing.

Comment: Oracle is non-compliant with the standard in this case. Using `AS` for a table alias is standard SQL, and is supported in most implementations. I never found a reason for why Oracle does not support it. I guess they always had something higher priority to work on, for the past 40 years!

Comment: @Ronald AS keyword for table aliasing is present in SQL:1992 standard.

Comment: @4LegsDrivenCat Thank you for pointing that out. I've deleted my post as I don't want to spread misinformation.

Answer (score 1):

Omit the `AS` for table alias in Oracle.

```
SELECT G.Guest_ID, G.First_Name, G.Last_Name
FROM Guest G
  JOIN Stay S ON G.Guest_ID = S.Guest_ID
WHERE G.City = 'Miami' AND S.Room = '222';
```

This will give you the output without errors.