# Why is sql command not properly ended being thrown?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, command, syntax-error

I am running a query using SQL embedded in Java. I have three tables in my database, QUERY, G1, and G2. All of them have the same schema of (SETID, GENEID).

The query I am running is as follows:

```
SELECT q.SETID, COUNT(q.SETID), g1.SETID, COUNT(g1.SETID) 
FROM QUERY AS q 
INNER JOIN G1 AS g1 ON q.GENEID = g1.GENEID 
GROUP BY q.SETID, g1.SETID
```

Partial code for execution:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
stmt = con.createStatement();
String sql = "SELECT q.SETID, COUNT(q.SETID) AS QSIZE, g1.SETID, COUNT(g1.SETID) AS GSIZE FROM QUERY AS q INNER JOIN G1 AS g1 ON q.GENEID = g1.GENEID GROUP BY q.SETID, g1.SETID";
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
```

When I run this, it throws the following error:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended. Could anyone please help me with this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a guess: Is it because of the missing semi-colon? Probably not, but I just want to be sure.

Comment: Post the actual code executing the statement.

Comment: Ubitsoft and piliapp both say it's fine, is there more code wrapping it that we could look at?

Comment: There is a known issue with the oracle driver and using ' AS ' for table aliasing. Try the following suggestion; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21145028/how-to-use-the-as-keyword-to-alias-a-table-in-oracle

Comment: Just added in the code used during execution. Also I tried to remove 'AS', but then it started to throw an invalid character error.

Comment: You should remove the `AS` only from the FROM and INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to:

1. Escape table name `QUERY` - it looks like reserved word
2. Add aliases to COUNT() columns - for example `COUNT(q.SETID) as Q_CNT`
3. Add semi-colon at the end
4. Remove table aliases like **@harvey** suggested

---

```
SELECT q.SETID, COUNT(q.SETID) as Q_CNT, g1.SETID, COUNT(g1.SETID) as G1_CNT
FROM `QUERY` AS q 
INNER JOIN G1 AS g1 ON q.GENEID = g1.GENEID 
GROUP BY q.SETID, g1.SETID;
```

---

```
SELECT QUERY.SETID, COUNT(QUERY.SETID) as Q_CNT, G1.SETID, COUNT(G1.SETID) as G1_CNT
FROM QUERY
INNER JOIN G1 ON QUERY.GENEID = G1.GENEID 
GROUP BY QUERY.SETID, G1.SETID;
```

Comment: I can't escape the table name as it throws an error saying it is an invalid character. The semi-colon and aliases also didn't seem to fix the issue.