# REF() function returns "SQL command not properly ended"

Tags: sql, oracle, ref

I'm trying to familiarize myself with a O/R db, which has led me to try to get object references.

Started out by listing all_objects for a specific user, and just picked one object (CF02) whose type is `TABLE` i.e. `OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'`

I then opened the table, and just went with one of the rows whose first field (`OBJECT_ID`) is `9142055040413031761`.

Then I tried to get the `ref()` on that row.

```
  SELECT ref(cf) FROM rdbmgr.CF02 as cf
  WHERE OBJECT_ID = 9142055040413031761
```

Hoping to get a similar result to that in the Oracle books, which is an internalnumber for the location of the object...

Comment: Nothing to do with ref - remove the `as` from `as cf`. [You can't use `as` for table aliases in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21145028/266304).

Comment: i tried that, it then gives me the error "CF":invalid identifier

Comment: Is `CF02` a table of an object type, or a normal table with a object column? Please include the relevant DDL in your question.

Comment: in the ALL_OBJECTS table, under the OBJECT_TYPE column, it comes up as 'TABLE'

Comment: i'm also not sure how i would get the DDL - i didn't make this db. - but i would assume that SELECT * ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE' would only list the Tables of an object type...

Comment: `select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'CF02', 'RDBMGR') from dual;` but you'd either need powerful privs or be logged in as `rdbmgr`. And you might need to `set long 5000` or similar to see it all. And they you need the DDL for the object type(s) too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a `ref()` function if your table was created from object type.

> `REF` takes as its argument a correlation variable (table alias) associated with a row of an **object table** or an **object view**.

e.g. you have an object type:

```
create or replace TYPE t_pos AS OBJECT 
( 
  x number,
  y number
)
/
```

you can create a table

```
 CREATE TABLE position OF t_pos ;

-- insert some data for test
insert into position values (1,2);
```

so you have a table `position`
now you can so a select with a `ref` function

```
select ref(t) from  position  t;
```

**Result**:

```
REF(E)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000280209587CADBD96F74009BBF01C1596D74E72E7986EC7F3AF40B4A264DA1BE6FE27D30040B2
790000
```

if you table was created as `create table position(x number, y number)`
you can't use `ref` function in your `select`

Have a look at documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions127.htm)

Comment: thank! so,an object table has to have been created using an object type for oracle to offer any kind of references on the objects within the table... i guess because even though they are similar objects, they're not technically the same object type?